# restFul API : failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, api, rest, php-include

I'm working on a restful API in php.
All is working on localhost, but when I try to put it on my server, I have these errors :

```
Warning: include_once(/path/to/api/simpletodo_api/Models/TodoItem.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homez.338/login/www/path/to/api/simpletodo_api/index.php on line 6

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/path/to/api/simpletodo_api/Models/TodoItem.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /homez.338/login/www/path/to/api/simpletodo_api/index.php on line 6
```

Here my include :

```
include_once 'Models/TodoItem.php';
```

index.php and the "Models" folder are in the same folder (in local and on my server).

I'm pretty sure it is a path error, but I can't find the right one.

Have you an idea of the path ?

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

If your server is Linux-based and your localhost is on Windows, you may be running into file naming errors. File paths in Linux are case-sensitive. Just to be sure prepend the `__DIR__` constant to your PHP path like so: `include_once __DIR__ . 'Models/TodoItem.php';`

Comment: I did `include_once __DIR__ . '/Models/TodoItem.php';`. Still working on my localhost, but again, on my server, I have this error :  `include_once(__DIR__/Models/TodoItem.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory [...] `

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507